# RFC-32 Date format to Short Date (MM/DD/YYYY) with ASP Classic

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, rfc822

I'm not a strong ASP Classic developer, but I am tasked with supporting this application at work, well I've been trying to convert an RSS feed date to a short date format. And I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have this format:

```
Wed, 10 Jun 2009 12:46:13 +0000
```

and I need to get it into this format:

```
06/10/2009
```

So far I have been tinkering with this RSS feed script for ASP:

```
<%
' change the RSSURL variable to the exact URL of the RSS Feed you want to pull
RSSURL = "{url to rss feed}"

Dim objHTTP ' this object is used to call the RSS Feed remotely
Dim RSSURL,RSSFeed ' these variables hold the URL and Content for the RSS Feed
Dim xmlRSSFeed ' this variable hold the XML data in a DOM Object
Dim objItems,objItem, objChild ' these variables are used to temporarily hold data from the various RSS Items
Dim title,description,link '  these are local variables that will hold the data to be displayed
Dim pubDate 
Dim RSSOutput ' variable will hold the HTML that was converted from the RSS Feed

' this code requests the raw RSS/XML and saves the response as a string <RSSFeed>
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "GET",RSSURL,false
objHTTP.send
RSSFeed = objHTTP.responseText

' this code takes the raw RSSFeed and loads it into an XML Object
Set xmlRSSFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
xmlRSSFeed.async = false
xmlRSSFeed.LoadXml(RSSFeed)

' this code disposes of the object we called the feed with
Set objHTTP = Nothing

' this is where you determine how to display the content from the RSS Feed

' this code grabs all the "items" in the RSS Feed
Set objItems = xmlRSSFeed.getElementsByTagName("item")

' this code disposes of the XML object that contained the entire feed
Set xmlRSSFeed = Nothing

' loop over all the items in the RSS Feed
For x = 0 to 3
    ' this code places the content from the various RSS nodes into local variables
    Set objItem = objItems.item(x)
    For Each objChild in objItem.childNodes
        Select Case LCase(objChild.nodeName)
            Case "title"
                  title = objChild.text
            Case "link"
                  link = objChild.text
            Case "description"
                  description = objChild.text
            Case "pubdate"
                  pubDate = objChild.text
        End Select
    Next
    ' Format display output
    RSSOutput = RSSOutput & "<tr><td valign='top' style='width:75px; height: 34px;' class='addresstext2'><b>"& pubDate &"</b></td><td valign='top'><a class=ccc href=""" & link & """>" & title & "</a></td></tr>"      

Next
```

%>

As I get pubDate from the RSS, I believe it is a string, and when I try to CDate it, I get a Type mismatch, I have also tried Format() and same deal.  Can anyone suggest a method to format this date to what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rss uses the format specified in [RFC822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html).

I found a function in [this thread](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=141970):

```
function parseRSSDate(sRSSDate)
'   take RFC822-formatted date string and return VBScript date object
'   ie: "Fri, 13 Jun 2008 16:33:50 GMT" 

dim sDay, sMonthName, sMonthNum, sYear, sHour, sMinute, sSecond
dim oRE, oMatches, oMatch
dim sDate, oDate

set oRE = new regexp
    oRE.IgnoreCase  = True
    oRE.Global      = True
    oRE.Pattern     = "^([A-Za-z]{3}),\s([0-9]{1,2})\s([A-Za-z]{3})\s([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})"
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(sRSSDate)
        if oMatches.count > 0 then
            set oMatch = oMatches(0)
                sDay        = oMatch.SubMatches(1)
                sMonthName  = oMatch.SubMatches(2)
                sMonthNum   = monthVal(sMonthName)
                sYear       = oMatch.SubMatches(3)
                sHour       = oMatch.SubMatches(4)
                sMinute     = oMatch.SubMatches(5)
                sSecond     = oMatch.SubMatches(6)
                sDate = sMonthNum & "/" & sDay & "/" & sYear
                oDate = cDate(sDate)
            set oMatch = nothing
        end if
    set oMatches = nothing
set oRE = nothing
parseRSSDate = oDate
end function
```

it also calls a function called monthVal, which just returns a number for a month name:

Code:

```
function monthVal(sMonthName)
' return month number (1-12) from month name
dim rv
dim aMonths : aMonths = Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
for i = 0 to uBound(aMonths)
    if sMonthName = aMonths(i) then rv = i+1
next
monthVal = rv
end function
```

Comment: Awesome, that was quick! Thank you, I can't believe I missed that there, I couldn't find any results for RSSDate format, etc via google.

Comment: No problem. I knew the rss date format was RFC822 so I searched for that in combination with vbscript and/or asp parse.